DynamoDB Single Table Design Modeling
I want to model my database efficiently but my entity relationships are a bit complex and I can't figure out how to do this in the best way possible. My application has the following entities:

Account
User
Campaign
Conversation
Message


A company creates an account
Employees at the company create users that belong to the parent account
Employees (users) can create campaigns as well as subscribe to campaigns created by other users on the same account
A Campaign has many conversations and I need to be able to get all conversations of a campaign
A Conversation has many messages

My current design is to have PK of ACCOUNT#ID. SKs are USER#ID, CAMPAIGN#ID, CONVERSATION#ID and MESSAGE#ID. I then will use Global Secondary Indexes to map users to the campaigns they subscribe to, as well as map conversations to the campaigns they belong to and then finally map all messages to conversations they belong to.
The issue with this approach is that indexes don't solve the users subscribing to campaigns pattern. My only other idea is to create a subscriptions table or to duplicate the campaign records in the table - the first time will be the account/campaign mapping and the duplicate will be the user/campaign mapping.
Am I relying too much on GSIs or is this how they're intended to be used? I'd be using one generic GSI in this case.
